# How to Split NSString to multiple Strings after certain number of characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am developing an iOS app using Xcode 4.6.2.

My app receives from the server lets say for example 1000 characters which is then stored in NSString.

What I want to do is: split the 1000 characters to multiple strings. Each string must be MAX 100 characters only.

The next question is how to check when the last word finished before the 100 characters so I don't perform the split in the middle of the word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex-based solution:

```
NSString *string = // ... your 1000-character input

NSString *pattern = @"(?ws).{1,100}\\b";

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: pattern options: 0 error: &error];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];                            
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    [result addObject: [string substringWithRange: match.range]];
}
```

The code for the regex and the `matches` part is taken directly from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html), so the only difference is the pattern.

The pattern basically matches anything from 1 to 100 characters up to a word boundary. Being a greedy pattern, it will give the longest string possible while still ending with a whole word. This ensures that it won't split any words in the middle.

The `(?ws)` makes the word recognition work with Unicode's definition of word breaks (the `w` flag) and treat a line end as any other character (the `s` flag).

Notice that the algorithm doesn't handle "words" with more than 100 characters well - it will give you the last 100 characters and drop the first part, but that should be a corner case.

Comment: If my string that I want to split is only 180 characters, It would split to two strings. There is only one issue, If I write like 60 characters and press return or enter it will split the first string to 60 chars. So 180 will be split to three strings. Any idea how to solve that? @Monolo

Comment: @iMubarak If I understand your question correctly, you want it not to break at line breaks if the 60 characters haven't been reached yet. If so, just add an `s` flag to the pattern. I have updated the answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Big Thanks for the response. One las thing, how to make it controlled by the user like if the user type 60 chars and want to cut the line he just type something like // or whatever. Is that possible? Last thing, is there any website that explain the reges ?? Thanks a lot. @Monolo

Comment: @iMubarak That's certainly possible with a regex, but it is beginning to sound like the problem is more complex than your first description of it, and then regexes may not be the best fit. At any rate, a good regex site is: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: The whole concept is to let the user type or paste any text and then the app split the input to 100 chars max for each string.  Everything is working perfectly. I just want add this feature where the user can split before reaching 100. Just like how the return key did before your last edit. @Monolo

Comment: @iMubarak Not sure I understand why you wouldn't use a line break character to denote a line break in your input, but at any rate, having thought about it I am no longer so sure that you can easily construct a regex to handle your requirements. They are best at simple problems.

Answer (score 0):

(assuming your words are separated by a single space, otherwise use `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:range:`)

Use `NSString -- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask range:(NSRange)aRange` with:

1. `aString` as @" "
2. `mask` as `NSBackwardsSearch`

Then you need a loop, where you check that you haven't already got to the end of the string, then create a range (for use as `aRange`) so that you start 100 characters along the string and search backwards looking for the space. Once you find the space, the returned range will allow you to get the string with `substringWithRange:`.

(written freehand)

```
NSRange testRange = NSMakeRange(0, MIN(100, sourceString.length));
BOOL complete = NO;
NSMutableArray *lines = [NSMutableArray array];

while (!complete && (testRange.location + testRange.length) < sourceString.length) {
    NSRange hitRange = [sourceString rangeOfString:@"" options:NSBackwardsSearch range:testRange];

    if (hitRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        [lines addObject:[sourceString substringWithRange:hitRange];
    } else {
        complete = YES;
    }

    NSInteger index = hitRange.location + hitRange.length;
    testRange = NSMakeRange(index, MIN(100, sourceString.length - index));
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code or any tutorial link? Thanks @Wain

Answer (score 0):

This can help

```
- (NSArray *)chunksForString(NSString *)str {
    NSMutableArray *chunks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    double sizeChunk = 100.0; // or whatever you want
    int length = 0;
    int loopSize = ceil([str length]/sizeChunk);
    for (int index = 0; index < loopSize; index++) {
        NSInteger newRangeEndLimit = ([str length] - length) > sizeChunk ? sizeChunk : ([str length] - length);
        [chunks addObject:[str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(length, newRangeEndLimit)];
        length += 99; // Minus 1 from the sizeChunk as indexing starts from 0
    }

    return chunks;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `NSArray *words = [stringFromServer componentsSeparatedBy:@" "];`
this will give you words.

if you really need to make it nearest to 100 characters, start appending strings maintaining the total length of the appended strings and check that it should stay < 100.